# capturing li content with jquery .each()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

Using jQuery and AJAX to submit a form, my PHP file does all the validation and returns one of two responses.

In case of success:

```
<div id='formres'>1</div>
<div id='formresposta'>
    <h2>SUCESSO</h2>
</div>
```

or this (not submitted, errors found):

```
<div id='formres'>0</div>
<ul>
    <li>errnome</li>
    <li>errmail</li>
    <li>errmsg</li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery I wrote so far manages to do what I want except taking action in case errors are found... here it is:

```
    $("#formcontacto").submit(function () {
        var dados = $(this).attr("action");
        $.post(dados,{
            nome:$(".nome").val(),
            email:$(".email").val(),
            telefone:$(".telefone").val(),
            mensagem:$(".mensagem").val()
        },
        function (dados) {
                resultado = $(dados).filter(function(){ return $(this).attr("id") == "formres"}).text();
                alert(resultado);
                if(resultado == 1){
                    $("#formcontacto").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#formcontainer").html(dados).fadeIn(3000);
                }else{
                    alert(dados);
                    var erros = $(dados).filter(function(){ return $(this).is("li") }).text();
                    alert(erros);
                    erros.each(function() {
                    if ($(this).text() == 'errnome'){ $('.nome').css({'border':'1px solid #a00','background-color':'#ffbaba','color':'#222'}); }
                    if ($(this).html() == 'errmsg'){ $('.mensagem').css({'border':'1px solid #a00','background-color':'#ffbaba','color':'#222'}); }
                    if ($(this).html() == 'errmail'){ $('.email').css({'border':'1px solid #a00','background-color':'#ffbaba','color':'#222'}); }
                    })
                }
            });
        return false;

    })
```

I don't know why the .is("li") isn't working and I also feel I'm way overcomplicating this ... any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dados (data) is the url and then later the return value.  @AfonsoGomes - can you show us the returned html?

Comment: dados is the response from process-form.php .... that php files returns 1 of the first 2 blocks of codes I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for json, what i totally would consider for things like that.

You can create an PHP Array to your wishes and convert it with:

```
 json_encode($array)
```

Then you can easily request the file, similar to your .post function:

```
$.getJSON('your.php', { your: options }, function(data) {
  if(data.formres == 1){
     // Everything is ok
  } else {
     // Something went wrong, so print the problems
     $.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
       $("#result").append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
     });
});
```

The JSON would look like following:

```
{
  "formres": "1",
  "errors": {
    "1": "wrong name",
    "2": "wrong email",
    "3": "wrong whatever"
  } 
}
```

*Note that JSON in PHP is available from PHP 5.2.0.
Also the code is untested*